# How to select an element in a List of N using Where extension function?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ienumerable

Suppose I have a class AddressType defined as is:

```
public class AddressType {
    public int AddressTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Having a List object in code, how do I select an AddressType object with a known AddressTypeId property?

I have never used the List.Where extension function....

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all `AddressType` objects in the list having a specific ID by using `Where`:

```
IEnumerable<AddressType> addressTypes = list.Where(a => a.AddressTypeId == 123);
```

But if you only want the one and only `AddressType` having a specific ID you can use `First`:

```
AddressType addressType = list.First(a => a.AddressTypeId == 123);
```

This will find the first `AddressType` in the list having ID 123 and will throw an exception if none is found.

Another variation is to use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
AddressType addressType = list.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressTypeId == 123);
```

It will return `null` if no `AddressType` having the requested ID exists.

If you want to make sure that exactly one `AddressType` exists in the list having the desired ID you can use `Single`:

```
AddressType addressType = list.Single(a => a.AddressTypeId == 123);
```

This will throw an exception unless there is exactly one `AddressType` in the list having ID 123. `Single` has to enumerate the entire list making it a slower than `First`.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<AddressType> addressList = ...
IEnumerable<AddressType> addresses = addressList.Where(a => a.AddressTypeId == 5);
```

or:

```
IEnumerable<AddressType> addresses = 
    from address in addressList
    where address.AddressTypeId == 5
    select address;
```